# Sorting Strings of a List<string>

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting

Guys I have a List having string like

```
1.For value <,20.(#GJHG)

2.For value <,2.(#bfHG)

3.For value <,15.(#vsfgvf)
```

I need to sort these string in descending order.
Like

```
1.For value <,20.(#GJHG)

2.For value <,15.(#vsfgvf)

3.For value <,2.(#bfHG)
```

How do I proceed ?

Comment: Try with sorted list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx And I am not sure how each string is stored, if you will sort on the existing values in case they are stored as: "1. For value<,20.(#GJHG)" (i.e. first one), then you need to break the strings first to reach at apporpriate integer value to sort with. I would also suggest to try sorting them when you are storing them

Comment: sorting them when storing them is not possible that is why I am faced to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to do this. It will work for you.

var max = myList.OrderByDescending(v => int.Parse(v.Substring(2))).ToList();